# Проблема при возвращении DOM элементов

Tags: javascript, dom

Добрый день, при попытке возвращения псевдомассивов нужно указывать на элемент а как вернуть все?

```js
function findel(el) {
el = document.querySelectorAll(el);
el = Array.prototype.slice.call(el);
return el;
}
console.log(findel('.text')) // div, div, div, div
console.log(findel('.text').innerHTML) // undefined
```

```html
<div class="text">123</div>
<div class="text">123</div>
<div class="text">123</div>
<div class="text">123</div>
```

Comment: а что ты хочешь вернуть?

Comment: Все дивы с таким классом )

Comment: Я знаю что можно через foreach но что в нем писать чтобы вернуть все

Comment: ну так ты его сейчас и возвращаешь, собственно `findel` и возвращает массив всех найденных элементов, непонятно что еще ты хочешь получить

Comment: а почему undefined?

Comment: _а почему undefined?_ очевидно потому, что у **массива** нет свойства `value`

Comment: мне нужно [123, 123, 123, 123]

Comment: если у тебя есть три дива с разным текстом внутри, что именно ты хочешь получить обращаясь к свойству value?

Comment: Исправил на innerHTML но эффекта никакого

Comment: _Исправил на innerHTML но эффекта никакого_ - перечитай предыдущий комментарий:  у **массива** нет свойства `innerHTML`

Comment: @Duoxx ты хоть сам понимаешь, что пишешь?)) к чему именно ты пытаешься применить innerHTML ?

Comment: Ну а почему если я напишу console.log(findel('.text')[0].innerHTML) А почему тогда так получается?

Comment: @Duoxx потому что это элемент **массива**. Может тебе все же почитать книжечки по js?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, jquery портит людей :-D стирает разницу между коллекцией элементов и единственным экземпляром

Comment: Я jquery юзаю редко..

Answer (score 0):

В современном js ввели такую штуку как [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), теперь не нужно никаких Array.prototype.call.

```js
function findel(el) {
  el = document.querySelectorAll(el);
  el = Array.from(el);
  return el;
}
console.log(findel('.text')) // div, div, div, div
console.log(findel('.text').map(el => el.innerHTML))
```

```html
<div class="text">123</div>
<div class="text">123</div>
<div class="text">123</div>
<div class="text">123</div>
```

Comment: на map стоило ссылку добавить, так как именно он проблему решает, а не `Array.from`